# How to get MemoEdit and Store in Access Database?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I used Memo Edit to Display Address, so it contain 4 lines. How to get this 4 lines and how to store it in the Access Database ? Normally if its EditText we Used this code to store

```
string inno = textEdit12.Text.ToString();
OleDbCommand top = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO invoice_top(invoice_number,order_number,customername,status,subtotal,tax,total,[date]) VALUES (" + inno + "," + odrno + ",'" + name + "',"+ chk1 +" ,"+ subtottal +","+ tax +","+total+",'"+date+"')", conn);
top.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

this code work for EditText. How to Get and Store it for MemoEdit ??? 
Help me.

Comment: Have you tried to use the memoEdit.Text property? What the exact problem you are running into? Saving the string into database? And how this problem is related to MemoEdit itself? 
p.s. It is not necessary to use `textEdit12.Text.ToString()` because the `textEdit12.Text` is already string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1. use a memo column in your Access database
2. use a parameter sql query

Code:

```
'Suppose you have 2 columns , A - a Memo one, B a DateTime one:
dim SIRCON as string = "your connection string"
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(SIRCON)
  conn.Open()
  Try
  Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (A, B)  VALUES (?,  ?)", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_A", textEdit12.Text.ToString())
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_B", DateEdit1.EditValue)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
Finally
 conn.Close()
End Try
```

End Using